# Image size validation in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel5 official documentation i get validation rules here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-size . For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes. And according to it i make a rules for validation image file:

```
'property_image'         => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif|size:200'
```

But its expect exactly 200K size image. So, I want min, max size or range for validation image. Is there anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'property_image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif|max:200'
```

btw. there's no `jpg` mime, [image/jpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is proper mime type.

Comment: The Laravel docs give this example of the `mimes` validation rule: `'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'`

Comment: @ceejayoz yup, that's correct. ``jpeg`` only, not ``jpg,jpeg``